# Display an image in a <div>, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

The value of ig is being transfered fine, but I need to put this image into an image, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
var ig = '<img src='+$(this).attr('src')+' style="z-index:1">';
$('#big').val(this)
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Guys I want to do it without .appendTo or .append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use.html instead,

```
var ig = '<img src='+$(this).attr('src')+' style="z-index:1">';
$('#big').html(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ig = $('<img />').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).css('z-index', 1);
$('#big').append(ig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html` instead of `.val` and pass `ig`. `.val` is used for manipulating form elements.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `html` or `appendTo` instead of `val`.

```
var ig = '<img src='+$(this).attr('src')+' style="z-index:1">';
$('#big').html(ig);  // replaces contents
```

or

```
$(ig).appendTo('#big'); // appends to existing contents
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **append** instead of **val**

```
var ig = '<img src='+$(this).attr('src')+' style="z-index:1">';
$('#big').append(ig);
```

working example: http://jsbin.com/agoye3

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, if #big is already an image, you can just change the image source:

```
<img id='big' src='theoldimage.jpg'>

<script>
  $('#big').attr("src", 'thenewimage.jpg');
</script>
```